# Getting Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds error while using MySql(5.7.31)

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

Since  i'm not to sure what to do other then what i've seen on here and stackoverflow but i'm getting this error when i startup MySql in WampServer: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds error. I've tried lowering and raising the values of these variables and this is what i have it set to now innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10M
innodb_log_file_size = 2G innodb_log_buffer_size = 10M in my my.ini config file the only way i've been able to overcome this error was by setting innodb_force_recovery to level 6 but then mysql is in read only mode and i need to create some more tables in my db any suggestions would help thanks

here's the whole error let me know if you need to see more of the log or more variables in my config file

```
InnoDB: ###### Diagnostic info printed to the standard error stream
2021-02-23T18:25:17.237395Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
2021-02-23 13:25:17 0x3a8c  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 14988 in file ut0ut.cc line 918
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
18:25:17 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete a bunch of data from a large table? See this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98809 and https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88523

Comment: no i'm not committing any transactions this error occurs upon startup of wampserver the only things i modified in the config file are these settings innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10M innodb_log_file_size = 2G innodb_log_buffer_size = 10M and innodb_force_recovery = 3

Comment: i've been told the schema as a potential issue i know i imported a group of tables into to my database and overwrote a couple of predefined tables in the phpmydadmin database provided by wampserver one of them being this table 
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `columns_priv`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `columns_priv` (
  Columns here) could this be causing the error?

Comment: That could be an issue, yes. At this point, if you are not on a production system, uninstall and reinstall wamp. If you have a last known working backup, you can restore from it. I’d recommend not changing any table manually in MySQL schema. The table that you touched contained column privileges.

Comment: yeah i'm just going to do that